Homology of a Chain Complex is a Group
Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category. Let $C_\bullet$ be a chain complex in $\mathcal A$,
$$C_\bullet: \cdots \xrightarrow{d_{n+1}} C_n \xrightarrow{d_n}C_{n-1} \xrightarrow{d_{n-1}}\cdots$$
nLab defines the chain homology of degree $n$ as
$$H_n(C_\bullet)=\frac{\ker(d_{n-1})}{\text{im}(d_n)}$$
nLab goes on to say that $H_n(C_\bullet)$ is an abelian group, though I don't quite understand this point. If $\mathcal A$ is $\textbf{Ab}$, then this is obvious. Similarly, if $\mathcal A$ is the category of $R$ modules over some commutative ring $R$, the statement is also intuitive. However, given any arbitrary abelian category, I'm not sure how the group structure arises.
The above statement seems to imply that every object in an abelian category is a set which can be made into a group. A very quick Google search confirms that this statement is wrong, and so I don't have any intuitive way of making sense of the statement that $H_n(C_\bullet)$ is a group.

It's a typo on the nlab, or at least (as we just saw) a bit misleading choice of terminology. The homologies are objects of the abelian category. See also Proposition 3.1 on the same page, the target of the homology functor is just the given abelian category. For example, the homologies of a complex of abelian sheaves are abelian sheaves themselves.
I suggest that you fix it on the nlab. The nlab is a community-driven project, just like Wikipedia (but with less hurdles to change articles).
PS. The stacks project made the same mistake. There you can also report mistakes via the comment system or GitHub directly.

The nLab article says things like "suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category like abelian groups or $R$-modules... then...."  So I wonder if the article was written assuming things were in a "concrete" abelian category of typical algebraic objects and not a general abelian category.  Either way, yes, wrong and a little bit sloppy.

No, I believe this is just to have some specific examples in mind. But yes again something one can improve with an edit. Go ahead! :)

Or maybe you are right. Some properties of the homology listed on the page are not valid for arbitrary abelian categories. This should be improved for sure.
